# Bootstrap tabs stop working when I change JS version to 3.3.7

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've checked Bootstrap documentation on v 3.3.7 but perhaps I have missed something.

My issue is that my dropdown (below) is not working when I use CDN for Bootstrap JS v3.3.6, but it does when I change it to v3.3.7.

However when I change to v3.3.7, my tabs no longer work.

When I remove the Bootstrap JS link, the tabs work again.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Quiz App!</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="http://plainicon.com/dboard/userprod/2921_4eb4c/prod_thumb/plainicon.com-64851-256px-36c.png">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">


</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h2 id="header"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-grain"></span> <small>(in development)</small></h2> </hr>
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="/" aria-controls="home2" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span></a></li>
                <li role="presentation" class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Featured Topics<span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="/topics/us-presidents" data-toggle="tab">U.S. Presidents</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/topics/business" data-toggle="tab">Business & Investing</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/topics/astronomy" data-toggle="tab">Astronomy</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/topics/movies" data-toggle="tab">Movies</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="/all-quizzes" aria-controls="rankings" data-toggle="tab">All Quizzes</span></a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="/create-quiz" aria-controls="stats" data-toggle="tab">Create a Quiz</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

        {{{body}}}
</div>
</body>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</html>
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Does the JS file actually load?  Check your browser console

Comment: @EatPeanutButter thanks for your reply, when I check chrome console I don't see any of the "Failed to load resource" messages. That said, I do not see it listed under Sources, whereas I do see Bootstrap CSS and Fonts files listed under the Sources tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root of your problem is the href of your links inside tabs. In order for the bootstrap js to work, links should be referencing **local content**, for example some div id, like:

`<a href="#all-quizzes" aria-controls="rankings" data-toggle="tab">All Quizzes</span></a>`

Bootstrap js hits it's head on the relative path in your link and throws an error (you can see it in the console, when you click on the tab).

If you look inside the bootstrap 3.3.7 source code for [tabs.js](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.3.7/js/tab.js), you'll see that it checks (line 29) the data-target attribute of the clicked element (tab) and if it's empty, falls back to href (line 32). Then it tries to use this value as a jquery selector (line 51) to find the element, which fails in your case.

For example, when you click on All Quizes tab, the js tries to do this: 
`$('/all-quizzes')` and that throws an error, because it is not a valid jquery selector.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up switching over to a nav bar and it is working. Thanks again for your insight.